# AttributeError: 'map' object has no attribute 'extend' in matplotlib setup

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, setuptools, distutils, distribute

I cloned the git `master` branch of `matplotlib` and I got to build it in Mac OSX. When I try to do the same in x86_64 GNU/Linux I get this output and error:

```
BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
        matplotlib: yes [1.3.x]
            python: yes [3.3.1 (default, May  7 2013, 17:57:31)  [GCC
                    4.8.0]]
          platform: yes [linux]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
             numpy: yes [version 1.7.1]
          dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.1]
           tornado: yes [using tornado version 3.0.1]
         pyparsing: yes [using pyparsing version 2.0.0]
             pycxx: yes [Official versions of PyCXX are not compatible
                    with Python 3.x.  Using local copy]
            libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                    be found. Using local copy.]
          freetype: yes [version 9.22.3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./setup.py", line 133, in <module>
    result = package.check()
  File "/home/khyox/matplotlib/setupext.py", line 808, in check
    min_version='1.2')
  File "/home/khyox/matplotlib/setupext.py", line 429, in _check_for_pkg_config
    ext = self.get_extension()
  File "/home/khyox/matplotlib/setupext.py", line 821, in get_extension
    CXX().add_flags(ext)
  File "/home/khyox/matplotlib/setupext.py", line 716, in add_flags
    ext.sources.extend(glob.glob('CXX/*.cxx'))
AttributeError: 'map' object has no attribute 'extend'
```

I traced the error to the PNG (`libpng`) package parsing. I tried with several versions of this library (1.2.49, 1.5.16 and 1.6.2), all supported by `matplotlib` (should be version 1.2 or higher for `libpng`), but this not solved the issue. Looking for helping differences, in Mac OSX I compiled Python3.3 with Clang 4.1 (said to be GCC 4.2 compatible) and in this x86_64 GNU/Linux machine, I used GCC 4.8.0, but I hardly believe that the problem could be related with this...

Any clue? Thank you very much in advance!

---

**Solution**: As suggested by @DSM in the comments below, a workaround is to edit *setupext.py* and, in the function `make_extension(name, files, *args, **kwargs)` just add this line:

```
    ext.sources = list(ext.sources)
```

after the line:

```
    ext = Extension(name, files, *args, **kwargs)
```

On the other hand, @tcaswell pointed out the suspect of the issue: `distutils`. In short, in order to install all the dependencies for `matplotlib` I used `distribute3` and its last release overrides the class `distutils.core.Extension` converting its `sources` member to a `map` instead of a `list` (it is expected to be a list of strings, as documented in [docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/3.3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.Extension)).

Entering in more details, if we add some debugging stuff, the output becomes:

```
BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: yes [1.3.x]
                python: yes [3.3.1 (default, May  7 2013, 17:57:31)  [GCC
                        4.8.0]]
              platform: yes [linux]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
Call distutils.core.Extension constructor with name=test and files=[]
Printing (ext = distutils.core.Extension).sources : <map object at 0x7f920c869e50>
The map object is empty!
                 numpy: yes [version 1.7.1]
              dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.1]
               tornado: yes [using tornado version 3.0.1]
             pyparsing: yes [using pyparsing version 2.0.0]
                 pycxx: yes [Official versions of PyCXX are not compatible
                        with Python 3.x.  Using local copy]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
Call distutils.core.Extension constructor with name=test and files=[]
Printing (ext = distutils.core.Extension).sources : <map object at 0x7f9208e81490>
The map object is empty!
              freetype: yes [version 9.22.3]
Call distutils.core.Extension constructor with name=matplotlib._png and files=['src/_png.cpp', 'src/mplutils.cpp']
Printing (ext = distutils.core.Extension).sources : <map object at 0x7f9208e81510>
The map object is empty!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 133, in <module>
    result = package.check()
  File "/home/khyox/matplotlib/setupext.py", line 817, in check
    min_version='1.2')
  File "/home/khyox/matplotlib/setupext.py", line 438, in _check_for_pkg_config
    ext = self.get_extension()
  File "/home/khyox/matplotlib/setupext.py", line 830, in get_extension
    CXX().add_flags(ext)
  File "/home/khyox/matplotlib/setupext.py", line 725, in add_flags
    ext.sources.extend(glob.glob('CXX/*.cxx'))
AttributeError: 'map' object has no attribute 'extend'
```

So, instead of being a `list`, the `sources` member of `ext` appears as a `map`. What is more, it fails to contain the source files when passed to the constructor, as seen for the `matplotlib._png` case, that is, when processing the `libpng` extension.

I followed the source of such strange behavior to the file *extension.py* of the `setuptools` provided by `distribute3` (see last line):

```
class Extension(_Extension):
    """Extension that uses '.c' files in place of '.pyx' files"""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        _Extension.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
        if not have_pyrex():
            self._convert_pyx_sources_to_c()

    def _convert_pyx_sources_to_c(self):
        "convert .pyx extensions to .c"
        def pyx_to_c(source):
            if source.endswith('.pyx'):
                source = source[:-4] + '.c'
            return source
        self.sources = map(pyx_to_c, self.sources)
```

Nevertheless, in the last `distribute` commit (newer than the last one of `distribute3`), it seems to be solved:

```
class Extension(_Extension):
    """Extension that uses '.c' files in place of '.pyx' files"""

    if not have_pyrex:
        # convert .pyx extensions to .c 
        def __init__(self,*args,**kw):
            _Extension.__init__(self,*args,**kw)
            sources = []
            for s in self.sources:
                if s.endswith('.pyx'):
                    sources.append(s[:-3]+'c')
                else:
                    sources.append(s)
            self.sources = sources
```

So, once `distribute3` will be synchronized with `distribute` this problem will probably disappear. Until then, the hack suggested by @DSM is working.

Comment: I suspect your issue is with `distutils` being out of date on your linux box.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion @tcaswell. I see it updated: entering `>>> import distutils as du` and `>>> du.__version__`
results in `3.3.1`.

Comment: nope, that isn't it (works fine on my machine with 2.7.4, but I am installing for python2.7)

Comment: Thanks again @tcaswell. By the way, for installing the packages dependencies for matplotlib, I used the last release of [distribute3](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/distribute3), so in this case `distribute-0.6.36dev-py3.3`.

Comment: Well, something along the code path clearly didn't make the right conversion from 2 to 3.  That's the error you get if someone used `map` expecting it would result in a list.  With a bit of work you could probably track down where the assumption was made.  (As a temporary hack, if you add `ext.sources = list(ext.sources)` right before this error and similar ones, it should work.)

Comment: Thank you very much @DSM, your hack solved the problem. I followed your suggestion and tracked down where the problem was originated... and as pointed out by @tcaswell, it was related with `distutils`... but not because being out of date: the `distutils.core.Extension` being (badly) overwritten in _extension.py_ by the `setuptools` provided by `distribute3`. I am going to ask for `distribute3` to be synchronized again with `distribute` because its last release keeps `distutils.core.Extension.sources` as a `list` and it does not convert it to a `map` as does the current `distribute3` release.